I am Using Auth0 service for Authentication, But redirecting back is showing error. server_error: Unable to issue redirect for OAuth 2.0 transaction
import { AppState, Auth0Provider, User } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const Auth0ProviderWithNavigate = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  const domain = import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
  const clientId = import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;
  const redirectURI = import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_CALLBACK_URI;

  if (!domain || !clientId || !redirectURI) {
    throw new Error("Unable to initialise Auth");
  }

  const onRedirectCallback = (appState?: AppState, user?: User) => {
    console.log("User: ", user);
    console.log("AppState: ", appState);
  };
  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      authorizationParams={{ redirectURI: window.location.origin }}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};

export default Auth0ProviderWithNavigate;


This is the Function where i have defined auth0. All the Env variable are correct and triple checked. I am using "@auth0/auth0-react": "^2.2.4", Can Anyone help regarding that.
I have tried different solutions published in the stackoverflow and the official website of Auth0 i.e Auth0.com But haven't found any solution that worked for me.

did you verify the values of your environment variables at runtime:?
console.log("Domain: ", domain);
console.log("Client ID: ", clientId);
console.log("Redirect URI: ", redirectURI);
